# "Semitic languages" in Classical Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, history, word-choice, linguistics

The term *semiticus* is attested in *Rudimenta linguae Hebraicae* (C. H. Vosen, 1883) but I am more interested in Classical Latin.

In English, the expression "Syro-Arabian languages" is sometimes used but I don't know if such a compound is of good latinity.

Comment: The idea of language families dates to like the 17th century.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Similarities between Hebrew and Arabic were noted in the Middle Ages (and possibly before).

Comment: Christians and Muslims in the Middle Ages thought all languages descended from Hebrew, but that doesn't translate to having a conception of distinct language families. Van Boxhorn in the 17th century seems to have been the first to posit a grouping of languages descended from a common ancestor ("Scythian") based on similarities between languages while also *excluding* other languages from that group (Hebrew, specifically).

Comment: @Cairnarvon Even if this were true, I fail to see how this world view would prevent the existence of a certain word to refer to some related languages/peoples. Thanks.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Christians yes (maybe), Muslims no. Muslims believe that God spoke Arabic.

Comment: @Victor If they didn't realize they were related, how could they have a name for them?

Comment: @fdb - Medieval Muslims believed that God spoke Arabic *while transmitting the Quran*, or that Arabic was the first, divinely appointed language? I have trouble believing the latter: Islam is largely built on Judaism and the Jewish Tanach, so they would have had some idea of people from long ago speaking Hebrew.

Comment: @Cairnarvon and it took until the 19th century until there was a systematic comparison between Latin and the Germanic languages (German, English, etc.). This is all old hat today but was a real area of inquiry a few hundred years ago.

Comment: @Cairnarvon whilst it is true that the idea of language families as we understand them today wasn't recognised, there was a recognition that some peoples spoke languages that were similar but not the same. In most cases though they seem to have just said things along the lines of "they spoke a language like that of the X" where X is a better known people speaking a related language. In this case I suspect "like the language of the Syrians" would probably be the closest to a term for the Semitic languages

Comment: @Obie2.0 iirc the Qur'an states that each prophet received their revelation (which was functionally equivalent to Islam) in their native language. Whilst there is some latitude to assume their native languages were all Arabic I believe those prophets who were Jews were generally assumed to have received their revelation in Hebrew instead. The idea that Arabic is the unique language of revelation (and therefore of Allah) appears to be a more recent innovation

Answer (score 15):

While fdb is absolutely correct that the ancient Romans had no conception of language families, we can come up with a plausible calque—a literal translation of each component of a word or phrase.

English "Semitic" comes from German *semitisch*, "pertaining to Semites", from French *sémite*, "descendant of the biblical patriarch Shem". So we can analyze the English word as having three components: "the patriarch Shem", "descendant of ___", "pertaining to ___".

The first component is easy enough to translate into Latin, since we just have to look at the Vulgate, where Shem is transcribed as *Sēm* (via Greek Σήμ).

For the second component, you could use *-ānus*, as in *Julius* > *Juliānus* and *Domitius* > *Domitiānus*. Using this for a group of people associated with a particular origin was not uncommon, as in *Romānī* "Romans" or *Christiānī* "Christians".

Finally, you could also use *-ānus* for the third, but applying that suffix twice to the same word just sounds wrong. Instead, I would use the mostly-synonymous *-icus* (which is also cognate with -ic, -isch, -ικος, etc).

The end result is *Sēmānicus*, as in *linguae Sēmānicae*. I think this calque would make enough sense to an ancient Roman, if they were given the context that some populations were thought to be descended from Shem, and people wanted to talk about the languages of those populations collectively.

However, if your audience is not ancient Romans, I would recommend instead just borrowing the English form and using *Sēmīticus*. It's much clearer to an English-speaker (or a speaker of any modern language, really, since the technical term is widespread). And the *-īt-* suffix should also be at least moderately familiar to a well-educated Roman, since it comes from Greek -ιτης. It might not be as immediately recognizable as the Latin *-ān-*, but an educated patrician would be acquainted with Greek nouns like ὁπλίτης ("shield-person", i.e. hoplite) and πολίτης ("polis-person", i.e. citizen).

Also, in *post*-Classical Latin, this suffix became very popular thanks to the Vulgate; a later Latin-speaker would easily see the parallel between *Sēmīta* "Semite" and words like *Lēvīta* "Levite" (someone from the tribe of Levi). While the idea of Semitic languages (or of certain populations being "Semites") wasn't established until much later, the word would be understandable enough to someone in the fourth century.

Comment: Cf. [*Asianus* v. *Asiaticus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4471/what-is-the-difference-between-asianus-and-asiaticus/4473#4473). I'd say the average Roman could handle either just fine, though.

Answer (score 7):

The ancient Romans had no concept of language families, nor of Semites (the supposed descendants of Noah’s son Shem). There is consequently no word for “Semitic languages” in Classical Latin.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out, the Romans did not have a concept of language families as we understand them today. They did however have a concept of some peoples speaking languages that were similar to or "the same" (presumably close enough that the author, who may not have understood either language well, could not distinguish them) as other languages they were more familiar with.

The Semitic-speaking people the Romans would have had the most familiarity with would have been the Carthaginians (note that Punic remained in use in parts of Africa, especially Tripolitania, right up until the Muslim conquest, and there is evidence of people being taught it as a classical language in Rome even after the Punic wars), probably followed by the Syrians (who would have spoken various Aramaic varieties).

With that in mind, I suspect that they would have referred to Semitic languages as "*sermōnēs similēs Pūnicae*" "languages like Punic" or "*sermōnēs similēs Syricae*" "languages like Syrian".

It's unclear which languages they'd have recognised as fitting which labels though.

Punic was much less conservative than Aramaic in this era, having lost the gutturals (retaining only a single /h/ mostly from earlier /χ/) and possibly merged most of the sibilants (communis opinio is that this definitely occurred, but I'm skeptical as the argument frequently relies on evidence that couldn't actually distinguish either way). It did still maintain a three-way distinction between the voiceless, emphatic, and voiced stops although it's possible the emphatics had lost their glottalisation or pharyngealisation. As the Greeks and (educated) Romans seem to have perceived the emphatics' lack of aspiration (which was present on the voiceless stops) as their distinctive characteristic though (and this is certainly preserved) this likely isn't a particular concern.

We know that Punic & Hebrew were recognised as closely related in late antiquity as St Augustine leans heavily on his native Punic in interpreting scripture. Prior to the complete displacement of Punic script with Latin for writing it the orthography was also extremely close to Hebrew so that even if a Carthaginian and Judaean would struggle to understand each other's speech, they wouldn't have too much difficulty in writing (noting that knowledge of Paleo-Hebrew, which would have had clear parallels with Punic script, unlike the square Aramaic script, does seem to have continued into the Roman era as Hasmonean coinage frequently contains it).

Similarities between Punic & Aramaic would probably have been much less obvious, although those between Aramaic and Hebrew would also likely have stood out. As such I suspect that Hebrew could reasonably have been described in either of these ways, but that Hebrew (and Phoenician-proper) would likely be the only languages identified as similar to Punic.

I suspect that Akkadian (which was retained as liturgical language in Mesopotamia into the Common Era) would not have been recognised as related. The Arabic of the Nabataeans, Palmyra, and Hatra probably would be, albeit on fallacious grounds (these peoples all used Aramaic for their inscriptions, which could easily be recognised as akin to that of the Syrians, and the Arabic actually spoken by their peoples may have been taken as a debased form of this Aramaic, rather than an independent, but related language).

I suspect other Semitic languages would lack enough obvious similarity for the Romans to have realised they were related.

Comment: Especially since Punic had by then lost many of the distinctive sounds that might be recognized in the other languages, like emphatic consonants, pharyngeals, and a lot of sibilants.

Comment: @Draconis Punic did retain distinct emphatics (represented in Latin Neo-Punic as t & c, where the voiceless stops were represented ph, th, & ch). The lack of aspiration seems to be what Greeks and (educated) Romans considered distinctive of the emphatics anyway so a lack of glottalisation/pharyngealisation (which is far from certain) isn't especially relevant. I'm skeptical of the common claim that the sibilants had merged, from what I can see Punic was reasonably consistent in spelling these in Punic characters, it just didn't always agree with Hebrew

Comment: the loss of gutturals is more significant, and might make it trickier to recognise the similarity. I thought the similarity would still be recognised because the native Punic orthography was still conservative and extremely similar to that of Hebrew. I guess once Latin script displace Punic that would be less significant though and the similarity may no longer have been as obvious

Comment: so overall I think Hebrew's similarity to Punic would have been clear (St Augustine certainly seems to rely on his native Punic in understanding Hebrew). Aramaic might have been a little less obvious, but the similarity between Aramaic & Hebrew would probably also have been clear. They may have incorrectly assumed Hebrew was similarly close to both Aramaic & Punic, but I do think both similarities would have been obvious

Comment: I'll add some discussion of this to the answer

Comment: This really deserves its own question, so I'll go ask that in a minute, but in brief: as you said, the native orthography was very conservative, so the distinction between the sibilant letters could have been a fossil like the use of the various gutturals.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good site for it as an alternative question. I don't the orthography is as consistently conservative as you suggest. Whilst the conservative spellings are (for the most part) the most common, there is frequent confusion between the laryngeals that isn't seen in the sibilants, and later on the definite article starts being spelt with an aleph most of the time